# Issue While Deserializing Authentication object in OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, serialization, oauth-2.0

I have OAuth2 implementation in Old project, say v1, with Spring+ hibernate 3. In current new implementation, say v2, We have upgraded Hibernate with hibernate 4. 
In both cases, Database is same. In authentication object we were persisting one Entity class, say User.java which includes

```
@ManyToMany
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Authority> authorities;
```

For v1, it is persisting well and retrieved also properly. But when we moved to v2, we are getting exception as below.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:626)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
```

This is becuase v1 has hibernate 3, which has package structure for PersistentBag as org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.
But v2 has hibernate 4, which has changed this package structure, org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.

Due to this deserialization of old Authentication object is failed in v2.

Can anyone suggest me good approach to achieve it?

Comment: Which hibernate dependencies are you including in the v2 project?

Comment: @dMcNavish :  hibernate-core (version 4.3.11.Final),                                              hibernate-entitymanager (version 4.3.11.Final),                                 hibernate-envers (version 4.3.11.Final) and                                     hibernate-validato (version 5.2.4.Final).